# Pandas dataframe returns False even if the values are equal

Tags: python, pandas

I've got an example:

```
+---------+---------+-------+
| 0       | 1       | Equal |
+---------+---------+-------+
| 3200    | 3200    | True  |
+---------+---------+-------+
| 3200.01 | 3200.01 | True  |
+---------+---------+-------+
| 8080.63 | 8080.63 | False |
+---------+---------+-------+
| 3408.81 | 3408.81 | True  |
+---------+---------+-------+
| 7080.01 | 7080.01 | False |
+---------+---------+-------+
| 2400.00 | 2400.00 | True  |
+---------+---------+-------+
```

The Equal column stores `True/False` values - `True` if column `0` and `1` are equal and `False` if not. The problem is that it does not always work - sometimes it adds False at random row even though it should be True and the numbers are equal

Column dtypes:

```
0                 float64
1                 float64
Equal               bool
dtype: object
```

I create `Equal` this way:
`df['Equal'] = df[0].ge(df[1])`
I also tried:
`df['Equal'] = df[0].eq(df.iloc[:, -2])`

Same problem all the time

It randomly returns False even though there shouldn't be False and now I am not sure if the values it returns as True are really correct or if it randomly gave True when there should be False, for example. How do I fix it?

Comment: please provide data in dictionary form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for equal use [`DataFrame.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

```
df['Equal'] = df[0].eq(df[1])
```

working like:

```
df['Equal'] = df[0] == df[1]
```

But because working with floats, there should be some accuracy problems, so use [`numpy.isclose`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html):

```
df['Equal'] = np.isclose(df[0], df[1])
```